# Magento 1.9.4.2 known issues: compatibility with third-party checkout extensions

Tags: onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout

Did anyone encounter a problem with a third party checkout extension like Amasty OPC or IWD OPC? I haven't upgraded yet to Magento 1.9.4.2 because I read in the release notes that:

"Third-party checkout extensions and closed security cases will either not work securely or will not work at all."

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1942

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use OneStepCheckout.com and the problem I have is after adding products to the shopping cart, they appear in the dropdown display of the shopping cart but the system says the Shopping Cart is empty when I click to display the shopping cart.  I see that there is a newer version of One Step Checkout and I will upgrade and test again and report here but that may be a few days because I must get approval for the expenditure.  I am working with a Development site so the delay is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I spoke with the OneStepCheckout developers and they say there are no problems between their extension and Magento 1.9.4.2.  Next I searched the internet to try and determine which PHP version is best for Magento 1.9.4.2  I could not find a definitive answer but it appears people using PHP version 7.0 are not having the problems being reported by people using PHP 7.1 or PHP 7.2.  I decided to change our PHP version to 7.0 and perform the upgrade from Magento 1.9.4.1 to Magento 1.9.4.2 again.  This time everything appears to be running without errors.  I even tested placing an order. All good.

Comment: Just so you know, I am using cPanel and Softaculous to perform the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  We also use IWD and are waiting for more info before upgrading our site.  Unfortunately PHP 7.0 isn't an option for a production store as PHP 7.0 has been deprecated so there are no security patches upcoming.